# unique spec page for a given record

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a basic scaffold for products.  I would like to have a unique spec page for each product.  The spec page will be made in regular HTML as each product has unique specs.  I figure I can simply create a file in the view and an appropriate route for the spec page.  My question is: how to create a link to the spec page from the product show action?

For example: say product one is Honda civic.  I will then manually create a spec file for civic, say spec_civic.html.erb.  I will then write out the specs for the spec_civic.html.erb in HTML.  Product two is Honda Accord.  I will make a spec sheet for spec_accord.html.erb  My question again is how to make a link from the product's show action that goes to its spec page.

Comment: What do you mean when you say a "spec page" and how would it differ from the "show" page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if File.exist?(File.join(Rails.root, "views", "cars", "_" + @car.model_name.underscore + ".html.erb"))
    render :partial => @car.model_name.underscore
else
    render :partial => "generic_car"
end
```

this code is not complete and is for example only. You can use it in controller's `show` action, or insert in `show.html.erb` (code needs to be modified for a view)

Comment: That's an interesting way to generate a file.

Comment: I wanted to make a link from the show to the spec page.  I guess I'll just do: <%= link_to "Spec page", :controller => "products", :action => "spec_" + @product.model_primary_name.downcase %>  and        get 'products/spec_civic'